# Transform Flat File without delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, text, ssis

I would like to transform flat file **test.txt** to flat file **test-output.txt**.

## Below the scheme:

---

**EXAMPLE INPUT: test.txt**

```
COD/ID:37
PRJ/NAME: Josephy Murphy
PRJ/EMAIL: jmurphy@email.com
PRJ/DESCRIPTION: test37, test37, test37 ...

COD/ID:38
PRJ/NAME: Paul Newman
PRJ/EMAIL: pnewman@email.com
PRJ/DESCRIPTION: test38, test38, test38 ...

.
.
```

---

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT: test-output.txt (pipe delimited without labels)**

```
37|Josephy Murphy|jmurphy@email.com|test37, test37, test37 ...
38|Paul Newman|pnewman@email.com|test38, test38, test38 ...
.
.
```

---

Links to screenshots:

[test.txt](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img540/2197/TdFkXJ.jpg)

[test-output.txt](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img540/603/ULRB68.jpg)

I want to import this file into SQL Server. But the file test.txt (15,000,000 lines) is not in default for import with delimiters.
I will use SSIS to import the data, but must be in CSV format or other format with delimiters.
I thought about using REGEX or SSIS Script Component. I know the import procedure by SSIS files with formatted text, but this file is not formatted.

Comment: Please put these texts (or at least comprehensive samples) in the question. And please share what you have tried. It is a must.

Comment: What's the difficulty? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to import this file into SQL Server. But the file test.txt (15,000,000 lines) is not in default for import with delimiters. I will use SSIS to import the data, but must be in CSV format or other format with delimiters. I thought about using REGEX or Script Component SSIS. What do you suggest?

Comment: The best option is to create a Source SSIS script component that splits the line using, eg the Regex by Florian Schmidinger, and returns one row per customer, then use other SSIS steps to process the rows and write them to a file. *Don't* use string manipulation functions, the temporary strings generated cause a huge strain to memory and garbage collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Regex for example:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"COD/ID:\s(?<id>\d+)\r\nPRJ/NAME:\s(?<name>.+?)\r\nPRJ/EMAIL:\s(?<email>\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)\r\nPRJ/DESCRIPTION:\s(?<description>.*?)(?:\n|$)");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string original = @"
COD/ID: 37
PRJ/NAME: Josephy Murphy
PRJ/EMAIL: jmurphy@email.com
PRJ/DESCRIPTION: test37, test37, test37 ...

COD/ID: 38
PRJ/NAME: Paul Newman
PRJ/EMAIL: pnewman@email.com
PRJ/DESCRIPTION: test38, test38, test38 ...";


            string result = string.Join(
                "\n",
                reg.Matches(original)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}",m.Groups["id"].Value,m.Groups["name"].Value,m.Groups["email"].Value,m.Groups["description"].Value)));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"COD/ID:\s(?<id>\d+)\r\nPRJ/NAME:\s(?<name>.+?)\r\nPRJ/EMAIL:\s(?<email>\S+?@\S+?\.\S+?)\r\nPRJ/DESCRIPTION:\s(?<description>.*?)\r\n");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder intermediateStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"YourInputPath.txt",true))
        {               
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("YourOutputPath.txt"))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        intermediateStringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WriteToFile(intermediateStringBuilder, writer);
                    }
                } 
                WriteToFile(intermediateStringBuilder,writer);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void WriteToFile(StringBuilder intermediateStringBuilder, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        Match m = reg.Match(intermediateStringBuilder.ToString());
        writer.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", m.Groups["id"].Value, m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["email"].Value, m.Groups["description"].Value);
        intermediateStringBuilder.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations! Perfect solution using regular expression (regex).

Comment: @J.LopesSilvestre yeah but with millions of lines you probably get in trouble with memory (i just read the comment of yours)... so this should be the example how to do it with smaller files

Comment: Really performance is impaired! The solution would then read line by line and writing to text file? Using the methods of System.IO; to read and write to text file.

Comment: @J.LopesSilvestre This approach would parse the entire content... with 15M lines you get in trouble... i'll try to implement a solution that can handle that... give me a few

Comment: Another solution could use SQL Server SSIS - Script Component (C#) using REGEX? Have you used the REGEX SSIS Script Component?

Comment: @J.LopesSilvestre added a performant solution for that amount of data... and no to be honest, i never used ssis before as it was not part of my query exam...

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger A good Regex is *more* performant because it *doesn't* generate temporary strings. The rest is IO and buffering, not related to parsing itself. You can improve this a lot by using a pipeline of asynchronous steps - that's essentially what SSIS already does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah i know that but how would you do it with 15 million lines... you have to buffer don't you?

Comment: You only need to buffer enough to avoid excessive IO. You can do that simply by passing the proper buffer size parameter to the StreamReader constructor. A couple of MB are far more than enough to cache a lot of rows. Loading everything in memory, parsing, then writing everything out would actually be slower, because no parsing can be done while a large file is loaded or saved. *Pipelines* like a SSIS dataflow, allow loading, parsing and saving to occur concurrently, in different threads so you can parse the current batch while the reader is reading the next batch

Comment: Congratulations! It worked perfectly! Thank You. Just a correction. For those who use the old version .Net version 3.5 need to adapt the code to work. Include method: private static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace (this string value)
         {
             if (value == null) return true;
             return string.IsNullOrEmpty (value.Trim ());
         }
And also change intermediateStringBuilder.Clear (); By intermediateStringBuilder.Length = 0;

Comment: @J.LopesSilvestre i hope it's performant enough... otherwise use panagoiotis advise...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex in this case since the context is known.

Use this:

```
public class EntryN
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }

   public EntryN()
   {
      this.id = this.name = this.email = this.description = string.Empty;
   }
   public string ToLine()
   { 
       return this.id + "|" + this.name + "|" + this.email + "|" + this.description; 
   }
}

var entries = new List<EntryN>();
using (var sl = new StreamReader(@"c:\YOURPATH.txt", true))
{
    var entry = new EntryN();
    var line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sl.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       if (line.StartsWith("COD/ID:"))
          entry.id = line.Substring(8).Trim();
       else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/NAME:"))
          entry.name = line.Substring(10).Trim();
       else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/EMAIL"))
          entry.email = line.Substring(11).Trim();
       else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/DESCRIPTION"))
          entry.description = line.Substring(17).Trim();
      else if (line.Trim() == string.Empty)
      {
          entries.Add(entry);
          entry = new EntryN();
      }
    }
    if (!entry.Equals(new EntryN()))
       entries.Add(entry);
    sl.Close();
}

var resulted = entries.Select(p => p.ToLine()).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: Another code with no separate class that will write directly without creating additional strings:

```
var id = string.Empty;
var name = string.Empty;
var email = string.Empty;
var description = string.Empty;
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"OUTPUT_FILE", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var sl = new StreamReader(@"INPUT_FILE", true))
    {
       var line = string.Empty;
       while ((line = sl.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           if (line.StartsWith("COD/ID:"))
              id = line.Substring(8).Trim();
           else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/NAME:"))
              name = line.Substring(10).Trim();
           else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/EMAIL"))
              email = line.Substring(11).Trim();
           else if (line.StartsWith("PRJ/DESCRIPTION"))
              description = line.Substring(17).Trim();
           else if (line.Trim() == string.Empty)
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", id, name, email, description));
               id = name = email = description = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        if (!new string[] {id, name, email, description}.Any(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)))
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", id, name, email, description));
        sl.Close();
     }
     sw.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please add your previous attempts to the question, BTW, even if they were unsuccessful. Before asking, always try at least something to post as proof of your efforts. Otherwise, your question will be closed, and eventually, deleted.

Comment: What is the acronym BTW?

Comment: This code has serious performance issues for large files due to the generation of a lot of temporary strings.  Each `Substring`, `StartsWith` and `Trim` call creates a new temporary string that must be garbage collected, straining both CPU and memory. A Regex *should* be used here as it doesn't generate any temporary strings making it far better for handling large files. Even splitting by `:` will be a significant improvement.

Comment: Also, the string concatenation in the end will also hurt performance due to the generation of temporary strings. This can be avoided by using [String.Join(string,IEnumerable<string>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx), eg: `String.Join("|",entries)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `entries` are not a string array or list, this is a `List<EntryN>` object.

Comment: I added `ToLine()` method to the `EntryN` class.

Comment: @stribizhev that's not a problem, you can use `String.Join` on objects as well.

Comment: If you use `string.Join("|", entries);` you will get `assembly.assembly_form+EntryN|assembly.assembly_form+EntryN`. When you read the whole file in and use an uncompiled regex, the performance will be even lower.

Comment: @stribizhev `ToLine` doesn't fix the problem, it's *still* string concatenation. This method will create 45M temporary objects. You should use String.Format or StringBuilder. Better yet, don't create a string at all, leave it to StringWriter.WriteLine to do the formatting

Comment: Oh my, this was just a sample for the Console.WriteLine or something, of course using `StreamWriter` is the way to use this whole `parser`. Ok, I will add the code.

Comment: @stribizhev as for loading the entire file - don't. This should only be done for *small* files and doesn't scale. Log processing typically involves processing the file one line at a time, using buffering and pipelines to achieve performance. That's what makes eg Powershell fast for such scenarios. Running a regex on each text line costs almost nothing.

Comment: Please now have a look at the update: no additional code, just the data we want, without concatenations, no regex on full text.